# Attempting to download a .xlsx file and upload to Azure Blob Storage using Playwright with Javascript produces malformed .xlsx file with a bad header

Tags: javascript, excel, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, playwright

I am trying to download an excel file and then upload it to Azure Blob Storage for use in Azure Data Factory. I have a playwright javascript that worked when the file was a .csv but when I try the same code with an excel file, it will not open in Excel. It says,
"We found a problem with some content in 'order_copy.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?:
After clicking yes, it says,
"Excel cannot open the file 'order_copy.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Any ideas on how to use the createReadStream more effectively to do this and preserve the .xlsx format?

I don't think the saveAs method will work since this code is being executed in an Azure Function with no access to a local known path.

My first thought was the content type was not right, so I set that, but it still did not work. I tried a UTF-8 encoder but that also did not work.

```
//const data = await streamToText(download_csv.createReadStream())             
const download_reader = await download_csv.createReadStream();
let data = '';
for await (const chunk of download_reader) {
    data += chunk; //---I suspect I need to do something different here
}
// const data_utf8 = utf8.encode(data) //unescape( encodeURIComponent(data) );

const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = "..." //---Removed string here
// Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
const blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING); 
// Get a reference to a container
const container_client = blob_service_client.getContainerClient('order'); 
const blob_name = 'order_copy.xlsx';
// Get a block blob client
const block_blob_client = container_client.getBlockBlobClient(blob_name);        
const contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
const blobOptions = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: contentType } };        
//const uploadBlobResponse = await block_blob_client.upload(data_utf8, data_utf8.length, blobOptions);
const uploadBlobResponse = await block_blob_client.upload(data, data.length, blobOptions);
console.log("Blob was uploaded successfully. requestId: ", uploadBlobResponse.requestId);
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

-Chad

Comment: What is `download_csv` in your code?

Comment: When you say "it will not open in Excel", could you be a little more specific in when you're trying to open it in Excel. Do you mean the file that you get when the download happens or the file that you get back out of the Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: Also, do you have access to the Excel file in uncorrupted form? If so, how does the corrupted file compare to it? Are the contents the same till a certain point or are they completely different? Use a diff tool to compare

Comment: @GauravMantri, the download_csv is determined after all promises have finished:
``` lang-js
const [download_csv] = await Promise.all([  // Wait for download    
    page.waitForEvent("download"),
    page.waitForEvent("popup"),
    page.locator('button:has-text("Export")').click()
]);
const path  = await download_csv.path()  // wait for download to complete and get path
const fname = await download_csv.suggestedFilename()
```

Comment: @neil - You are correct that after uploading to Azure Blob Storage, I download the file and that is when I find it is in the improper format. That is a good suggestion to try a diff tool to compare them. Is there a particular diff tools for Excel that you would recommend?

Comment: I believe the problem is that an Excel file is a binary file and you are trying to read it as a string. Please try to read it as a buffer (byte array). See this for an example: https://riptutorial.com/node-js/example/5547/reading-a-file-into-a-buffer-using-streams.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gaurav for the suggestion on not setting the data to a string. The following code worked after I changed to using a array of the chunks and concatenated it using the Buffer similar to your suggested code.

```
let chunks = []
for await (const chunk of download_reader) {
    chunks.push(chunk)
}
const fileBuffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)
...
const uploadBlobResponse = await block_blob_client.upload(fileBuffer, fileBuffer.length, blobOptions);
```

Thanks everyone!